# Form Recognizer Supported Documents except from Image and pdf

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I am able to process the Pdf and image invoice documents using Microsoft Form Recognizer. When I am trying to process the invoices as Microsoft-Word or excel document, It is throwing an error of "Unsupported document type".

According to officail documentation, Supported file formats are JPEG, PNG, PDF, and TIFF. Is there a way to process the documents in excel or word format apart from the formats mentioned?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form Recognizer does not yet support word or excel formats. Please convert these to PDF and then send them to Form Recognizer for extraction.